# Why does my jQuery calendar not display correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, calendar

I have some code which collects data from a db, then gives a specific class (`fc-closedDay`) to a certain div if the day is closed in the database.

Another part of the code gets the div with this specific class and, with `calendarAvailabilities`, configure the data (`cal.setData`) of the calendar (`calendario`) so the calendar is displayed correctly on the page.

The problem is here. The data is correctly collected. I made a `console.log(data)` and it is the good data that showed up. Sometimes, a bug shows up : all the divs get the class `fc-closedDay`. Even if this bug doesn't show up, the calendar does not display correctly. When I change the month of the calendar, one time the month is totally open, another time the month is totally closed, and another time the closed day is a mix of the data of 2 other month.

It's been 3 weeks I'm on this problem and I don't know what to do now. Can someone help me please?

Here is the function `getClosingDays` with the part which gets the data, the part which sets the div, and the part which sets `calendarAvailabilities` (`cal.setData`) :

```js
function getClosingDays(cal)
    {
        // Get closing days
        jQuery.get( "index.php?option=com_skydivespa&task=reservation.getClosingDays", {"month": cal.getMonth(), "year": cal.getYear()},
            function(data) {
            console.log(data);
                var periods = JSON.parse(data);
                // console.log(periods['data'][0].mon);
                if (periods['data'].length === 1) {
                    if (periods['data'][0].mon == 0) jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Lun')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                    if (periods['data'][0].tue == 0) jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Mar')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                    if (periods['data'][0].wed == 0) jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Mer')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                    if (periods['data'][0].thu == 0) jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Jeu')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                    if (periods['data'][0].fri == 0) jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Ven')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                    if (periods['data'][0].sat == 0) jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Sam')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                    if (periods['data'][0].sun == 0) jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Dim')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < periods.data.length; i++) {
                        var dateStartPeriod = new Date(periods['data'][i].date_start);
                        var dateEndPeriod = new Date(periods['data'][i].date_end);

                        if ((periods['data'][i].mon == 0)) {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Mon')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }
                        } else {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Mon')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").removeClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }
                        }

                        if ((periods['data'][i].tue == 0)) {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Tue')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        } else {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Tue')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").removeClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        }

                        if ((periods['data'][i].wed == 0)) {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Wed')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        } else {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Wed')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").removeClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        }

                        if ((periods['data'][i].thu == 0)) {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Thu')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        } else {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Thu')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").removeClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        }

                        if ((periods['data'][i].fri == 0)) {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Fri')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        } else {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Fri')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").removeClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        }

                        if ((periods['data'][i].sat == 0)) {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Sat')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        } else {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Sat')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").removeClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        }

                        if ((periods['data'][i].sun == 0)) {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Sun')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").addClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        } else {
                            for (var d = (parseInt(dateStartPeriod.getDate())); d <= (parseInt(dateEndPeriod.getDate())); d++) {
                                jQuery("span.fc-weekday:contains('Sun')").prev("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").removeClass('fc-closedDay');
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                for (let d =1; d <= 31; d++)
                {
                    let number = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {minimumIntegerDigits: 2});

                    let date = new Date(number.format(cal.getMonth())+"-" + number.format(d) + "-" + cal.getYear());
                    //let day = date.getDay();
                    if ($("span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')").parent("div").hasClass('fc-closedDay'))
                        calendarAvailabilities[number.format(cal.getMonth())+"-" + number.format(d) + "-" + cal.getYear()] = ['<span class="close uk-button uk-button-small uk-button-primary uk-margin-small">Close</span>'];
                    else
                        calendarAvailabilities[number.format(cal.getMonth())+"-" + number.format(d) + "-" + cal.getYear()] = ['<span class="free uk-button uk-button-small uk-button-primary uk-margin-small" onclick="validateResaStep1(\'9:00\')" slot="9:00:00">9:00-10:00</span>'];
                }

                getOpenDays(cal);
            });

    }
```

I tried async await, setTimeout. Unfortunately nothing changed. I don't know if I made a correct async await. I didn't tried something else because I'm lost.

Comment: A *very* quick look shows this: `span.fc-date:contains('" + d + "')")` - `d` will be `"1"` which will also match when span.fc-date contains 10,11,12...19,21 and 31.   Look on SO for a `:contains-exact`

Comment: It did solve another problem. The closed days are more correct like the db but it is not on the right month again

Comment: Debug your `date` calculations - eg: `let date = new Date(number.format(cal.getMonth())` should be `let date = new Date(number.format(cal.getMonth()+1)` - same for `calendarAvailabilities[number.format(cal.getMonth())+`  as `.getMonth()` is 0-based, so Jan=0, not 1, so you're creating a new date with previous month.

Comment: You have a crazy amount of repetition here. Look into the DRY principle and using loops to check all your values.

Comment: I tried the cal.getMonth()+1 but the closed day who shows up don't correspond to the div who has the class .fc-closedDays. I still have the problem that when I change the month in the calendar on the site, the month could be totally closed, totally opened or the closed days don't correspond. 
It's not my code by the way. I have to debug the code of the web dev who was here before me.  But I will try to use the DRY principle.